# Not able to communicate with host page from outlook dialog box using messageParent

Tags: dialog, outlook-web-addins

Not able to communicate from dialog box to the host page.

Am checking in both outlook desktop and outlook web

**OS** : windows 10

**Outlook desktop version**: 16.0.13901.20436 64-bit

**Browser and version**: Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

in the page opened in the dialog box, called Office. Initialize() and Office. onReady() functions,and on button click need to send information back to parent window.

In the dialog box console am able to see messageParent method but not receiving any call to the host page

**parent window code snippet**:

```java
var dialog
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {height: 30, width: 20},
function (asyncResult) {
dialog = asyncResult.value;
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,  function(arg){
    var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    if (messageFromDialog.messageType === "dialogClosed") {
        dialog.close();
    }
});
});
```

**dialog box code snippet**:

```js
    <script>
         Office.initialize = function (reason) {
};
    </script>
    
    <script>
        Office.onReady(function (_ref) {
    var host = _ref.host;
    console.log("In on ready function")
    console.log(Office.context.ui)
});
    </script>


  function closeWindow1() {
        var messageObject = {messageType: "dialogClosed"};
        var jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
        console.log(Office.context)
        console.log(Office.context.ui)
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsonMessage);
        console.log(Office.context.ui.messageParent)
        console.log("Called messageParent method")
        }
```

**logs in the console**:

```
Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
In on ready function
OSF.DDA.UI.ChildUIaddHandlerAsync: ƒ ()messageParent: ƒ ()removeHandlerAsync: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
Office.context
OSF.DDA.OutlookContext {contentLanguage: "", displayLanguage: "en-US", touchEnabled: false, commerceAllowed: true, host: "Outlook", …}
Office.context.ui
OSF.DDA.UI.ChildUI {messageParent: ƒ, addHandlerAsync: ƒ, removeHandlerAsync: ƒ}
ƒ (){var b=OSF._OfficeAppFactory.getHostFacade()[OSF.DDA.DispIdHost.Methods.MessageParent];return b(arguments,a)}
Called messageParent method
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find displayDialogAsync [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) here.

There are also sample codes available, which can be found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example).

Comment: Hi , thank you for the reply ..I checked the docs I didn't find any clue that would help us solve this.... did you find anything that we missed please let us know...

Comment: It is not clear when "closeWindow1" function is being called in your code as we don't have complete code. Please check example link given in our documentation.

Also, you need to use only one of the method for office initialization. Either use Office.initialize() or Office.onReady(). You can check details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in